# Django, JQuery and Updating img tag in html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

In my project, I would like to convert a pdf to image, then show it to the user on the screen.

I have created image under some directories. I have passed the path to the JQuery, however, it cannot find the path.

I pass the path below to the JQuery

```
{"path":"/home/USERNAME/Desktop/PROJECTNAME/src/FOLDER1/FOLDERID/pdf/image.png"}
```

When I inspect Network field in the browser, I can see this:

```
Using the URLconf defined in PROJECTNAME.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$
admin/
SUBFIELD1/
SUBFIELD2/ ^$ [name='index']
SUBFIELD3/
The current path, home/USERNAME/Desktop/PROJECTNAME/src/FOLDER1/FOLDERID/pdf/image.png, didn't match any of these.
```

Note that, SUBFIELD's and FIELD1 are not equal. Here is my folder schema under `src`

```
  FOLDER1
   FOLDERID
    pdf
     image.png
  SUBFIELD1
    migrations folder
    admin.py
    models.py
    ...
  SUBFIELD2
    same as SUBFIELD1
  SUBFIELD3
    same as SUBFIELD1
```

The JQuery code for showing image to the user

```
function getpdf()
{
$.getJSON('/SUBFIELD1/convertPdf2Image/',function (data) {
        $('#myimage').attr('src', '');
        $("#myimage").attr('src', data.path);   
    });
}
```

Html Code

```
<img id="myimage" style="width:500px;height:600px;"/>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Page not Found(404). I believe Django loooks for the url. It starts with /home... and the matching url's in the Django.urls file cannot match it.

Only the image has 404 error, other fields(divs etc) can load

Comment: You're passing a filesystem path for the image which won't work. The image needs to be accessible on a URL.